# Render problem - Two Questions

Tags: rendering

I used vertex paint to color it, but why isn't it showing up when I render it? Also what do I do when the texture doesn't show up?

Photo: http://prntscr.com/grsqlh

Comment: Vertex colors and textures don'r magically show up in renders alone. They have to be used in materials

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Oh! I am still learning, and I though so. I will do that.